# changing what program opens a flashdrive

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

When I insert my usb flashdrive it opens with the webshots desktop program. I want it to just open showing the files. I have tried changing autoplay but nothing works. I am running Windows 8.1

Comment: have you changed autoplay settings and it's saved correctly (next time you open it, it shows the status you set)? Does your flash contains an autorun file? Do all flash drives open the same way, or only one?

Comment: yes, the autoplay settings are saved. The flashdrive does not have an autorun file, and they all open the same way

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is if you have WinRAR, WinZip, 7-Zip installed, navigate to your flash drive, delete `autorun.inf`

If you dont have such software installed, you can follow [this guide](http://ccm.net/faq/4210-how-to-remove-autorun-inf-file) for removal of autorun.inf